# Should authentication token be encrypted?

Tags: security, authentication

If I append an HMAC to the auth token then the token cannot be tampered with. I notice many articles also recommend encrypting the token (which contains user id, expiration date and hash). What is the point of encrypting? Isn't that a waste of CPU time? (You have to decrypt the token for each request.) If it is not encrypted, anyone can see the user id and expiration date. What is the harm there?

Comment: Can you point out a few articles?

Comment: Here's one: http://eversystems.eu/Document/15/Sessionless_Authentication_with_Encrypted_Tokens

Comment: And another one: http://ezinearticles.com/?Sessionless-Authentication-With-Encrypted-Tokens&id=3537025

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only HMAC is a viable option: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki/wiki?HmacUserAuthentication

But: *Note from disadvantages*

> No privacy. If you need privacy, you need full encryption: use SSL.
>   HmacUserAuthentication is for security of service provision, not
>   privacy.

So encryption is a requirement if you use a plain connection. In case of SSL the additional encryption is needed only if you want to prevent the end user from reading the token.